# Encryption using AES on mysql, shortest URLs

Tags: php, mysql, url, encryption

this is my very first question.
Anyone can see that mega.co.nz uses advance encryption on data, like truecrypt does. I have an algorithm that encrypts a string using as paremeter the original text and a Secret Key:

```
function fnEncrypt($Value, $SecretKey)
{
    return rtrim(
        base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $sSecretKey, $sValue, 
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
                mcrypt_create_iv(
                    mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                    ), 
                    MCRYPT_RAND)
                )
            ),
        );
}
```

Both parameters, is given by the user. On mega.co.nz using your mouse an automatically secret key is generated, and this key encrypts evreything. How can I do something like that? And how mega.co.nz or other site with the same security stores this key in a database? having this key on a database is not secure, isn't it? 
Moreover, If the maximum text is 250 characters, the encryption will be much longer? We can calculate the length of an encrypted text? Using the maximum original string, 250 chars.

I am planing to develop an algorithm to make the URLs shortest so that to save space, but this is not valuable because the original URL must be stored on the database as well?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, mega.co.nz does use encrypt all user uploaded data. I believe they use AES (probably 128 bit length) algorithm to encrypt the data on the CLIENT side. In other words, JavaScript encrypts all the user data before it gets uploaded to Mega's servers.

The key is generated automatically but it IS NOT stored on Mega's servers - which is what makes this service so unique. The key is generated, JavaScript uses the key to encrypt the user data, and the encrypted data is uploaded to Mega. In the end the user is given an URL that can be used to retrieve the file. The URL is what contains the encryption key. Mega does not store the key in their database, that is how they ensure security of the encrypted data.

Only somebody with the correct URL can fetch and decrypt the uploaded data.